# I want to get mfrc522 readed data from ardiuno to my nodejs server using javascrip so can anybody know how to do it

Tags: node.js, rfid, node-serialport, johnny-five, mfrc522

I have ardiuno in which i have connected mfrc522 rfid reader , so i want the data which rc522 have readed from ardiuno. I have tried using have tried it using sketch which is written in cpp but i want it in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried routing through the `serial port` as suggested in [this](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/issues/804) ?